# Select distinct highest level directories from string in SQL

Tags: sql, string, postgresql, subquery, sql-like

Given a table Paths:

```
|                 path                 |
----------------------------------------
|/user/jdoe/project                    |
|/user/jdoe/project/my_db.db           |
|/user/jdoe/project/my_db.db/signal_1  |
|/temp/jdoe                            |
|/temp/jdoe/temp_db.db                 |
|/temp/jdoe/temp_db.db/temp_signal     |
```

How would one get the following output?

```
|        Paths      |
---------------------
|/user/jdoe/project |
|/temp/jdoe         |
```

This is all I could think of:

```
select min(path)
from Paths;
```

Comment: Do you need to distinguish folder names that are prefixes of each other, e.g. `aa` from `aabc`?

Comment: You can think of using ltree for path representation or use arrays for path representation. it will make the querying easier. http://www.monkeyandcrow.com/blog/hierarchies_with_postgres/ , https://coderwall.com/p/whf3-a/hierarchical-data-in-postgres

Comment: @VenkataramanR But how do you check whether one path is a prefix of another, and how to group them by their common ancestors?

Comment: @Bergi, when we store the path itself, we have to store considering the hierarchy, then it will be easier for us to query them in future. In SQL Server, there is hierarchyid datatype, especially for the hierarchical queries. In Postgres, we have to use ltree, it seems. I have not much worked on Postgres. Wanted to share the information with OP.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `NOT EXISTS`:

```
SELECT *
FROM paths p
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
    FROM paths p1
    WHERE 
        p1.path != p.path
        AND p.path LIKE p1.path || '/%'
)
```

As commented by Bergi, this can also be expressed with `bool_or`:

```
SELECT *
FROM paths p
WHERE NOT bool_or(
    SELECT 
        p1.path != p.path 
        AND p.path LIKE p1.path || '/%' 
    FROM paths p1
)
```

Comment: Clever! Maybe also `WHERE NOT bool_or(SELECT p1.path != p.path
        AND p.path LIKE p1.path || '%' FROM paths p1)`

Comment: I guess you should append a trailing slash (`LIKE p1.path || '/%'`) to prevent matching folder names partially

Comment: @Bergi: thanks for the suggestions! I updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

A variation on GMB's solution is simpler:

```
select t.*
from t
where not exists (select 1
                  from t t2
                  where t.path like t2.path || '/%'
                 );
```

But the most efficient method uses `lag()`:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*, lag(path) over (order by path) as prev_path
      from t
     ) t
where prev_path is null or path not like prev_path || '/%';
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=f0f3b21300e9e3e05de9f8ec01183410) is a db<>fiddle.

Note that this can use an index on `(path)` for the `lag()`.